# on IE some images not resizing properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, image-resizing

I have developed website in Wordpress. I am facing problem with IE comparability. In my website some of my images not working properly on IE11.
It is working fine with Firefox, Chrome, Safari

here is link to my website
http://103.53.42.224/synefra/home/
Here is screenshot on firefox in this section I am having problem

[image: Screenshot]

Screen of IE11.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Preferably as a snippet here in the question. (Edit the question, press the `<>` icon.)

Comment: Hi, Tools>ActiveX Filtering.... the other browsers do not have ActiveX filtering.... word press sites feed syndicated flash adds which fall back to sized (px) images if ActiveX Filtering in IE blocks the flash content.

Comment: see
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/02/28/activex-filtering-for-consumers/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/05/02/activex-filtering-for-developers/

Comment: @RobParsons I tried with ActiveX filtering blocking/unblocking but its not working on IE only that section has problem.